# Detect charge in android without battery

Tags: android, battery

I have a device connected directly to the pins of the `Tablet` (for charge it), not the battery. 
This makes the `Tablet` is **charging**, although in reality the **battery** is discharged or with little charge.

There is some method to detect that the `Tablet` is **charging**, even if the battery is not connected.
Obviously the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` does not work because the battery is not charging.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Better way to get change value you should use **BroadcastReceiver**

```
IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);

BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        float battPct = level/(float)scale;       
    }
};
```

Comment: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED does not work because the battery is not charging.. The tablet is connected directly to the pins

Comment: Will tablet remains ON even after removed the battery even though it is directly connected to supply!